# Instruction to get the current time on x86

Tags: performance, time, x86, instructions

Is there an x86 instruction to get the current time?

Basically... something like a replacement for clock_get_time ... something with the minimum overhead... where I don't really care about getting the time in any specific format... as long as it's a format I can use.

Basically I'm doing some work to "Detect how much PHYSICAL REAL LIFE TIME" has gone by... and I want to be able to measure time as frequently as possible!

I guess you can imagine i'm doing something like a profiling app... :)

I really need aggressively efficient access to the hardware time. So ideally... some ASM to get the time... store it somewhere... then massage it later into some format that I can actually process.

I'm not interested in _rdtsc as that measures the number of cycles gone by. I need to know how much physical time has executed... not cycles which can vary due to thermal fluctations or so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For profiling, often it's most useful to profile in terms of CPU clock cycles, rather than wall-clock time.  CPU dynamic clocking (turbo and power saving) makes it annoying to get the CPU ramped up to full speed before the start of a measurement period.

If you still need wall-clock time after that:

Recent x86 CPUs have a TSC that runs at a fixed rate, regardless of CPU frequency adjustment for power-saving.  Also, the TSC doesn't stop when the CPU is halted.  (i.e. no work to do, so it ran the `HLT` instruction to wait for an interrupt in low-power mode.)

It turned out that efficient access to a useful time-source was more useful to have in hardware than an actual clock cycle counter, so that's what `RDTSC` morphed into, a few CPU generations after its introduction.  Now we're back to using hardware performance counters for measuring clock cycles.

In Linux, look for `constant_tsc` and `nonstop_tsc` in the CPU features flags in `/proc/cpuinfo`.  IDK if there are `CPUID` bits for those.  If no, use Linux's code for it (if you can use GPLed code).

On a CPU with those two key features, Linux uses the TSC as its clocksource, IIRC.

The lowest overhead way to get the current time in user-space will be to work out the conversion between `RDTSC` ticks and real time.  While profiling, you might just store 64bit TSC snapshots, and convert to real-time later.  (So you can handle TSC wraparound then).  `RDTSC` only takes about 24 cycles (Agner Fog's instruction table, Intel Haswell).  I think the overhead of a system call will be an order of magnitude higher than that. (The kernel will have to do a `RDTSC` in there somewhere anyway).

Agner Fog has [documented his profiling / timing methods](http://agner.org/optimize/), and has some example code.  I haven't looked recently, but it might have useful stuff for this application.

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly the kind of answer I wanted! I wonder though... out of curiosity... how do people manage to find the CPU cycle count now that RDTSC returns the physical time?

Comment: @boytheo: With `perf stat ./myprog`.   `-e cycles` is part of the default output.  Also, I think the `rdtsc` clock speed matches the "rated" non-turbo frequency on Intel CPUs.

Comment: [Get CPU cycle count?](//stackoverflow.com/a/51907627) has more about RDTSC.  This answer is still correct, except that the `clock_gettime()`` is actually implemented in user-space (VDSO) on modern x86, using RDTSC.